# Google Classroom API with Swift

Tags: swift, google-contacts-api

I am developing an education-related app and I am planning on integrating the Google Classroom API to import information about the student's classes and assignments.  I already have Google Sign-In working, but I do not know where to go now.  I cannot find any documentation regarding using the Classroom API with Swift.  If anyone can give me some pointers on how to set this up, it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like there is a library to use Classroom in swift. You are going to have to write your own code to hit the API and consume the JSON. I would use something like [alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) to make the network requests for the JSON. Then use [codables](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/7/3/parsing-json-using-the-codable-protocol) to parse the JSON. [The google documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest) is going to be your friend to learn how to hit the API. If you don't know what an API is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YcW25PHnAA) youtube video should give a nice overview. If it still doesn't make sense, keep researching REST API's.

Best of Luck!